# Training Dialogflow Doubts

Tags: python, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am using python package `dialogflow` to connect to my dialogflow agent. I have 2 doubts regarding dialogflow agent training

1. When I add intents using RPC, do I need to explicitly train? And by train I mean call the `TrainAgent` function and wait for it to complete.
2. If I call TrainAgent twice in succession without waiting between those calls, will dialogflow train twice or just take the recentmost request and train once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Whenever you change anything in your intent, the training will be started automatically.
2. But if you want to explicitly start training your agent then you need to call "TrainAgent" function.
3. If you call the function twice, the agent training will start again only after the first training completes.

Answer (score 6):

Training will happen automatically each time you make a change to the agent and its intents. Calling TrainAgent twice will effectively restart the training from the second time that you call it.

Comment: Cool. So will the second training start after the first has ended?

Comment: The first training will be cancelled and the second training will start immediately.

Comment: I am not seeing that it gets cancelled. I started 2 train agents and collected the operation object in 2 different variables. The first one did not get cancelled. I checked using object.done().